# Trouble breaking from a method

Tags: java, for-loop, methods, boolean

I am having difficulties with my method returning true. It is a boolean method that takes two words and tries to see if one can be turned into the other by transposing two neighboring letters. I have had no troubles getting the false boolean. When the code gets to the for loop with an if statement in it it runs fine but does not return true when the if statement is satisfied. For some reason it continues through the for loop. For example, when comparing "teh" and "the" when the loop hits 1 the if statement is satisfied but does not return true, the for lo

```
public static boolean transposable(String word1, String word2)
    {
        ArrayList<Character> word1char = new ArrayList<Character>();
        ArrayList<Character> word2char = new ArrayList<Character>();
        int word1length = word1.length();
        int word2length = word2.length();
        int count = 0;
        String w1 = word1.toUpperCase();
        String w2 = word2.toUpperCase();
        if(word1length != word2length)
        {
            return false;
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < word1length; i++)
        {
            char letter1 = w1.charAt(i);
            word1char.add(letter1);
            char letter2 = w2.charAt(i);
            word2char.add(letter2);
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < word1length; i++)
        {
            char w1c = word1char.get(i);
            char w2c = word2char.get(i);
            if(w1c == w2c)
            {
                count++;
            }
        }
        if(count < word1length - 2)
        {
            return false;
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < word1length; i++)
        {
            char w1c = word1char.get(i);
            char w2c = word2char.get(i+1);
            if(w1c == w2c)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

op just keeps running. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How have you determined that the "for loop just keeps running"?

Comment: Also, as an aside, your final loop will throw an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` at the last character when accessing `word2char.get(i+1)`.

Comment: This seems like an overly complex method of doing this. If it were me, I would just take 1 word, and make a set of all the combinations of transposing 2 letters, and then checking if the 2nd word is in that set.

Comment: @Falmarri Your way sounds more complicated to me... the only thing really "complicating" the OP's code is thinks like e.g. manually/unnecessarily packing Strings into an ArrayList and such, but all that is (probably) incidental to the question being asked.

Comment: I guess saying the for loop keeps running was the wrong way to put it. I had the system print the i value right after the if statement to see when it got to a certain point and had the system print the two words inside the if statement. It looped once, printed 0, went back and printed the two words, then it printed 0 again and then 1 and then crashed.

Comment: What does "crashed" mean?

Comment: The program stopped working, I got the ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException that Jason C stated above.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the comments this doesn't seem to be the easiest way around this problem. Here is a solution which tries to follow your logic and includes the use of toUpperCase() and ArrayLists.

Going over your code it looks like you were getting a bit lost in your logic. This is because you had one method trying to do everything. Break things down into smaller methods and you also will benefit by not having to repeat code and it keeps things much cleaner. The code below is tested with Java8 (although there is no reason why this should not work with Java 7).

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    String word1 = "Hello";
    String word2 = "Hlelo";

    transposable(word1, word2);

}

private static boolean transposable(String word1, String word2) {
    // Get an ArrayList of characters for both words.
    ArrayList<Character> word1CharacterList = listOfCharacters(word1);
    ArrayList<Character> word2CharacterList = listOfCharacters(word2);

    boolean areWordsEqual;

    // Check that the size of the CharacterLists is the same
    if (word1CharacterList.size() != word2CharacterList.size()) {
        return false;
    }

    // check to see if words are equal to start with
    areWordsEqual = checkIfTwoWordsAreTheSame(word1CharacterList, word2CharacterList);
    System.out.print("\n" + "Words are equal to be begin with = " + areWordsEqual);

    if (!areWordsEqual) {

      /*
      This loop i must start at 1 because you can't shift an ArrayList index of 0 to the left!
      Loops through all the possible combinations and checks if there is a match.
      */
        for (int i = 1; i < word1CharacterList.size(); i++) {
            ArrayList<Character> adjustedArrayList = shiftNeighbouringCharacter(word2CharacterList, i);
            areWordsEqual = checkIfTwoWordsAreTheSame(word1CharacterList, adjustedArrayList);
            System.out.print("\n" + "Loop count " + i + " words are equal " + areWordsEqual + word1CharacterList + adjustedArrayList.toString());
            if (areWordsEqual) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    return areWordsEqual;
}

// takes in a String as a parameter and returns an ArrayList of Characters in the order of the String parameter. 
private static ArrayList<Character> listOfCharacters(String word) {
    ArrayList<Character> wordCharacters = new ArrayList<Character>();
    String tempWord = word.toUpperCase();

    for (int wordLength = 0; wordLength < tempWord.length(); wordLength++) {
        Character currentCharacter = tempWord.charAt(wordLength);
        wordCharacters.add(currentCharacter);
    }
    return wordCharacters;
}

// takes in two character arrayLists, and compares each index character.
private static boolean checkIfTwoWordsAreTheSame(ArrayList<Character> characterList1, ArrayList<Character> characterList2) {
    // compare list1 against list two
    for (int i = 0; i < characterList1.size(); i++) {
        Character currentCharacterList1 = characterList1.get(i);
        Character currentCharacterList2 = characterList2.get(i);

        if (!currentCharacterList1.equals(currentCharacterList2)) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

// this method takes in an ArrayList of characters and the initial index that we want to shift one place to the left. 
private static ArrayList<Character> shiftNeighbouringCharacter(ArrayList<Character> characterListToShift, int indexToShiftLeft) {
    ArrayList<Character> tempCharacterList = new ArrayList<Character>();
    int indexAtLeft = indexToShiftLeft - 1;

    // fill the new arrayList full of nulls. We will have to remove these nulls later before we can add proper values in their place.
    for (int i = 0; i < characterListToShift.size(); i++) {
        tempCharacterList.add(null);
    }

    //get the current index of indexToShift
    Character characterOfIndexToShift = characterListToShift.get(indexToShiftLeft);
    Character currentCharacterInThePositionToShiftTo = characterListToShift.get(indexAtLeft);

    tempCharacterList.remove(indexAtLeft);
    tempCharacterList.add(indexAtLeft, characterOfIndexToShift);

    tempCharacterList.remove(indexToShiftLeft);
    tempCharacterList.add(indexToShiftLeft, currentCharacterInThePositionToShiftTo);


    for (int i = 0; i < characterListToShift.size(); i++) {

        if (tempCharacterList.get(i) == null) {
            Character character = characterListToShift.get(i);
            tempCharacterList.remove(i);
            tempCharacterList.add(i, character);
        }
    }
    return tempCharacterList;
}
```

Hope this helps. If you are still struggling then follow along in your debugger. :)

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I forgot to post this yesterday but I ended up keeping my code exactly the same except I changed the for loop to stop 1 short of the array size so that it would not throw the exception. This seemed to solve my issue but I still am not sure why it didn't break at the return statement to begin with.

Comment: Also, I am in a beginner level class so I am just using things that we have covered. This was the easiest I could come up with.

Comment: Glad you managed to get your code working. A rule of thumb that might help you in the future is to ask yourself - "What does this method do?", where you find yourself saying "and" then that can suggest that you might need to move the part after the "and" into a separate method. For example "This method takes takes the characters from a String, puts them into an ArrayList, and checks to see if they are the same" should be two statements "This method takes takes the characters from a String, puts them into an ArrayList" and "This method checks to see if two ArrayList of Characters are the same."

Comment: Oh nearly forgot, another great thing to learn as soon as possible when starting out is how to use your IDE debugger. Eclipse and Intellij have excellent debugging features, just learn the basics so you can "step" through your code as it is executed. And finally, it might be because your class leader wants you to format your code in the way you did, but the Java Coding Conventions (http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/index-135089.html) say that curly braces "{}" should appear at the end of the same line as the declaration statement and  starts a line by itself (like in my answer).